# cannot launch node of type [A/B]: can't locate node B in package A

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have this strange problem, where ROS seems not to be able to find my executables.
I have a catkin workspace with several packages. Using `catkin_make`, all of them are being built.
I source the `devel/setup.bash` file in my `~/.bashrc`
I am using ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

Upon launching a `.launch` file, most of the nodes start just fine, but for all nodes of one explicit package I get the error:

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type
> [packageA/nodeB]: can't locate node
> [nodeB] in package [packageA]

Now, I have sourced the `devel/setup.bash` file, I can `roscd packageA`  and `find . -executable` shows me the subdirectories.

Using `rosrun packageA nodeB` gives me

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable
> named preprocessing below
> /home/user/catkin_ws/src/packageA

> [rosrun] Found the following, but
> they're either not files,

> [rosrun] or
> not executable:

> [rosrun]    /home/user/catkin_ws/src/packageA/src/nodeB

Thoughts:

- My setup is:
  catkin_ws/src/packageA/src/nodeB/nodeB.cpp
  <- could the subdirectory be a
  problem? But I am pointing catkin to
  the right directory in the
  CMakeListis.cpp
- I am sourcing 2
  workspaces. The second one with the
  `--extend` Flag. <- is this possibly
  a source for trouble?

Also I don't seem to be the only one with this problem. See:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/200019/error-cannot-launch-node-of-type-move_basemove_base-cant-locate-node-move_base-in-package-move_base/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/200891/cant-locate-node-naoqi_joint_states_cpp/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/194708/cannot-launch-node-of-type/

Does anyone have any hints to what could be going wrong here?

Also, tell me if you need more Information. Thanks

**UPDATE**
Running the command `catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec --share perception` returns:

> /opt/ros/indigo/share/perception

My package is called "perception" might this be a problem? Does it collide with a ros package? But if so, why did it never bring up an error until recently?
Running the same command on a different package returns:

> /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/navigation

> /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/share/navigation

> /home/user/catkin_ws/src/navigation

**UPDATE2**
Ohh... so now I was just playing around a little and commented out the other workspace in my .bashrc (the one with the extend flag). After that, I did a clean build and sourced. Now it's working again.
PS: I am using the `--extend` flag, because I am adding an extra Visualization/Debugging workspace that won't run on the robot but is only used on my machine.

I am trying to reproduce the error now, but uncommenting the other workspace again won't bring up the error anymore. Well anyway, I guess it's resolved for now.

Thanks @William for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201051/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Ba/b%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-b-in-package-a/) by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-01-15**:
Hello, did you: source the bashrc file after editing it? Try running on the console: source .bashrc

**Comment by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) on 2015-01-15**:
Yes I did. And as stated above, it finds the other packages, but just not this one. I also tried a clean build...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-15**:
The other thing to add to your question is the output of `catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec --share packageA`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-21**:
You should create an answer and accept it or accept my answer. (I converted the relevant comment to an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you doing the second source with `--extend`? I think this should work but it might be the source of your problem. Is the package you need in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`? Can `rosrun` locate other executables in this package?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0